# Reftex \cite command binding

Tags: emacs, reftex

I have a computer where the char `[` is made with `AltGr+è` so I can't use the command `Ctrl+[` of RefTeX. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: For the close-voters: I would wait with such decision and definitely not close a question after 3 minutes!

Comment: Hello and [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I'm not sure if this is really a question for this site. You want to define a different keyboard shortcut for the action than `Ctrl+[` ?

Comment: There isn't anything specifically TeX related about this question as I understand it. You're probably better off googling "[emacs change keybinding](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=emacs+change+keybinding)".

Answer (score 3):

I'm moving my comment here as it gives me more space:

But then again, there are quite a lot of `Emacs` + `reftex` users reading this site as well. `C-c [`, runs `reftex-citation`, you you could just define your own short cut. Here is what I would do

```
; unset C-z, to be used to make my own C-z prefix
(global-unset-key [(control z)])
(global-set-key [(control z) (c)] 'reftex-citation)
```

(untested)

The above is how I normally add my own short cuts. By using `C-z` as a prefix, I'm usually not messing with some existing ones.

Comment: Sure, there are lots of emacs+reftex users on this site. But there are lots of mathematicians on this site: that doesn't make maths questions on-topic. Some reftex related questions should count as on-topic (I think) but those relating just to generic emacs problems (such as this one) aren't on-topic.

Comment: @Seamus RefTeX is TeX-related extension of emacs so the question is IMHO boundary but fine.

Comment: But the question isn't _really_ about reftex. That's the point. It's asked as if it related to reftex, but as is obvious from your answer, there's nothing specific to reftex about the answer. Any other mode's keybindings could be reset in the same way.

Comment: I understand what @Seamus is saying and I'm sorry but daleif answer was very useful to me